# Custom accessor names in a specialised pair

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I would like to use an equivalent of `std::pair<bool, std::string>` as a function return type. In downstream code it would look better to use `ok` and `msg` instead of `first` and `second` accessors to avoid unnecessary API lookup. And I don't seem to be able to write it correctly using inheritance as `std::pair` may leak without virtual destructor. Wanted to avoid my own struct as the solution in [Renamed std::pair members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084089) - to reuse existing Move constructor and other plumbing. Is it possible at all?

Edit:

After the feedback seems to be that the recommended way to go is:

```
struct res {
    bool ok;
    std::string msg;
};

res fnk() { ...; return r };
```

Do I understand correctly that C++11 compiler expected to generate the move constructor to avoid copying the string?

Comment: The compiler provides all the necessary plumbing for you. What you don't get for free is the relational operators and an `std::make_pair` equivalent.

Comment: Are you saying that return of `r` in `struct res { bool ok; std::string msg }; res fnk() { ...; return r };` will automatically move value of `r` into the receiver when `fnk` returns?

Comment: It depends on how you call the function, but the most likely scenario is that you get copy elision. But the compiler will generate a move copy constructor and a move copy assignment operator for you (unless you define your own constructors, in which case you can re-enable them using `default`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-ctor-copy-ctor-and-default-assi)).

Comment: Thank you, this would address the need. Looks like it is not available in VC++2012 now and it will be available [after VC++2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344800) (next version after what I have). If I read [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-is-now-available/) correctly it is going to be not earlier than in a 2014 VC++ update.

Comment: I don't think the lack of virtual destructor would be a problem in this case...

Comment: @CygnusX1, should not, I do not add data. But then I am having a syntax issue - the only way I seem to do it is this `class res : std::pair<bool, std::string> { inline bool ok(){ return first; }; inline std::string msg() { return second; }; };`. Is there a way (or benefit) to "alias" `first` and `second` then? Greatly appreciate!

Comment: You are changing the semantics: you return values, not references, and you cannot call the method on a const `res` instance, or via `const` reference or pointer. As to the benefit, I don't see what you gain compared to `struct res {bool ok; std::string msg;};`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, I'll use references. As far as benefit, my compiler (from VC++2012) does not seem to generate move constructors ( [see the previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441900/custom-accessor-names-in-a-specialised-pair?noredirect=1#comment28827202_19441900) ) so I thought to get by using inheritance.

Comment: @VladDidenko In response to your edit: Yes, and the situation is even better: The compiler will hopefully create the return value in place! That means that even the (otherwise very cheap) move is avoided as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wanted to avoid my own struct as the solution in [Renamed std::pair members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6084089/341970) - to reuse existing Move constructor and other plumbing.

I believe this the source of the misunderstanding: If you write your own struct, [the compiler will generate the move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and "other plumbing" for you and for free.

And any decent compiler should be able to do [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), that is, construct the result in place; no copy, no move.

Using named inline accessors is also an option, especially if you *really* need to use `std::pair`; it is also detailed in the [Renamed std::pair members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6084089/341970) question and [in one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084943/341970).

Doing inheritance in this case would be a mistake in my opinion; I wouldn't do that. I don't see any benefit in it but I do see problems with it.