# Is it possible in C++ to do std::map<> "for element : container" iteration with named variables (eg, key and value) instead of .first and .second?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iteration, readability

I wasn't sure what to search for. 
I found [Renaming first and second of a map iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500064/renaming-first-and-second-of-a-map-iterator) but it's not quite what I want to do.

Here's what I'd like to do [see below for nonsense C++ code]. Is something close to this possible? Otherwise will just have to go with the option of "adapting" the iterator as the first line inside the loop I suppose.

```
// what I want to do:
std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
// ... populate my_map
for(auto key, auto & value: my_map){
    // do something with integer key and string value
}
```

C++11 is fine, but rather avoid boost if possible.

The closest I've gotten is

```
// TODO, can this be templated?
struct KeyVal{
    int & id;
    std::string & info;

    template <typename P>
    KeyVal(P & p)
        : id(p.first)
        , info(p.second)
    {
    }
};

//...
for ( KeyVal kv : my_map ){
    std::cout << kv.info;
}
```

But that means writing an adapter class for each map :(

```
// slightly joke answer/"what could possibly go wrong?"
#define key first
#define value second
```

Comment: [maybe someday](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0144R1.pdf)

Comment: This is why, even though my professional career has been nearly all C++, I like Python so much.

Comment: I think looping is not essential here. The problem is that the fields in the value type of `std::map` are called `first` and `second` instead of `key` and `value`.

Comment: to be clear, section 3.4 in the structured bindings paper explicitly calls this out

Comment: In the long run, you and all the other maintainers will be grateful if you stick to idiomatic c++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An approach inspired by Barry below would be to write a range adapter.

Doing this without `boost` or similar library support is a pain, but:

1. Write a range template.  It stores 2 `class iterator`s and has `begin()` and `end()` methods (and whatever else you want).
2. Write a transforming iterator adapter.  It takes an iterator, and wraps it up so that its value type is transformed by some function object F.
3. Write a `to_kv` transformer that takes a `std::pair<K, V> cv&` and returns a `struct kv_t { K cv& key; V cv& value; }`.
4. Wire 3 into 2 into 1 and call it `as_kv`.  It takes a range of pairs, and returns a range of key-values.

The syntax you end up with is:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;

for (auto kv : as_kv(m)) {
  std::cout << kv.key << "->" << kv.value << "\n";
}
```

which is nice.

Here is a minimalist solution that doesn't actually create legal iterators, but does support `for(:)`:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
struct kv_t {
  Key&& key;
  Value&& value;
};

// not a true iterator, but good enough for for(:)
template<class Key, class Value, class It>
struct kv_adapter {
  It it;
  void operator++(){ ++it; }
  kv_t<Key const, Value> operator*() {
    return {it->first, it->second};
  }
  friend bool operator!=(kv_adapter const& lhs, kv_adapter const& rhs) {
    return lhs.it != rhs.it;
  }
};
template<class It, class Container>
struct range_trick_t {
  Container container;
  range_trick_t(Container&&c):
    container(std::forward<Container>(c))
  {}
  It begin() { return {container.begin()}; }
  It end() { return {container.end()}; }
};
template<class Map>
auto as_kv( Map&& m ) {
  using std::begin;
  using iterator = decltype(begin(m)); // no extra (())s
  using key_type = decltype((begin(m)->first)); // extra (())s on purpose
  using mapped_type = decltype((begin(m)->second)); // extra (())s on purpose
  using R=range_trick_t<
    kv_adapter<key_type, mapped_type, iterator>,
    Map
  >;
  return R{std::forward<Map>(m)};
}
std::map<int, std::string> m() { return {{0, "Hello"}, {2, "World"}}; }
```

which is *very* minimal, but works.  I would not generally encourage this kind of half-assed pseudo iterators for `for(:)` loops; using real iterators is only a modest additional cost, and doesn't surprise people later on.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a0b3a05a8091304)

(Now with temporary map support.  Does not support flat C arrays ... yet)

The range-trick stores a container (possibly a reference) in order to copy temporary containers into the object stored for the duration of the `for(:)` loop.  Non-temporary containers the `Container` type is a `Foo&` of some kind, so it doesn't make a redundant copy.

On the other hand, `kv_t` obviously only stores references.  There could be a strange case of iterators returning temporaries that break this `kv_t` implementation, but I'm uncertain how to avoid it in general without sacrificing performance in more common cases.

---

If you don't like the `kv.` part of the above, we can do some solutions, but they aren't as clean.

```
template<class Map>
struct for_map_t {
  Map&& loop;
  template<class F>
  void operator->*(F&& f)&&{
    for (auto&& x:loop) {
      f( decltype(x)(x).first, decltype(x)(x).second );
    }
  }
};
template<class Map>
for_map_t<Map> map_for( Map&& map ) { return {std::forward<Map>(map)}; }
```

then:

```
map_for(m)->*[&](auto key, auto& value) {
  std::cout << key << (value += " ") << '\n';
};
```

close enough?

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dbb53bc93c314b1)

There are some proposals around first-class tuples (and hence pairs) that may give you something like that, but I do not know the status of the proposals.

The syntax you may end up if this gets into C++ would look something like this:

```
for( auto&& [key, value] : container )
```

---

Comments on the `->*` abomination above:

So the `->*` is being used sort of as an `operator bind` from Haskell (together with implicit tuple unpacking), and we are feeding it a lambda that takes the data contained within the map and returns void.  The (Haskell-esque) return type becomes a map over void (nothing), which I elide into void.

The technique has a problem: you lose `break;` and `continue;` which suck.

A less hackey Haskell-inspired variant would expect the lambda to return something like `void | std::experimental::expected<break_t|continue_t, T>`, and if `T` is `void` return nothing, if `T` is a tuple-type return a map, and if `T` is a map join the returned map-type.  It would also either unpack or not unpack the contained tuple depending on what the lambda wants (SFINAE-style detection).

But that is a bit much for a SO answer; this digression points out that the above style of programming isn't a complete dead-end.  It is unconventional in C++ however.

Comment: As far as proposals go, there's also the structured bindings - which is probably the most relevant one (`for (auto&& [key, value] : map) { ... }`)

Comment: I'm trying to decide whether I like this answer or not. After writing/being corrupted by C++ for a couple of years, I find it difficult to distinguish the Dark Side from the light...

Comment: I could probably live with loss of 'break'/'continue', but I wouldn't want to inconvenience co-maintainers of the code with a strange loop where ordinary logic doesn't apply.

Comment: @JamEnergy True.  Sketch of a half-decent solution inspired by  Barry's answer below added.

Comment: Oh my god, this actually works. http://pastebin.com/FVpfRxVg

It's a lot of work though, and I might not use it in real code. But it's here if anyone wants it. Should I edit it into this answer and mark it as the solution?
I haven't sorted out what should be copy by val, or pass by ref in the helper functions etc.

Comment: I'm also not sure about const (in)correctness. And it's a bit sad that we had to hardcode "key" and "value" names. Can't wait for structured bindings support.

Comment: @jam have not read your link yet, but you'll want a cv-lr-ref-transcription helper.  A `std::pair<K const, V> const&` becomes a `kv<K const&, V const&>` under the transforming iterator.  In C++14 you may be able to just return `auto` with a `make_kv` function call in `operator*` (note you cannot support `->` without extra work, but `for(:)` does not need it)

Comment: I like the range adapter. And with help of Boost it's not that pain at all :)

Comment: @oliora Turns out it isn't hard even without `boost`.  I exploited the fact we don't actually need iterators for `for(:)` loops under the standard to slack off.

Comment: @JamEnergy I wrote a simple version that handles const maps properly and is about half the LOC by exploiting the fact that `for(:)` loops don't actually need iterators.

Comment: What is the purpose of `decltype(x)(x)`?

Comment: @maxim perfect forwarding with `auto&&x`.  So first and second have right r/lvalue category.

Comment: Is it possible to move the minimalist version "to the top" of the answer, so people don't get put off by our "historical" attempts?

Then I will mark it as the solution. I don't want to mark "the rest" of the attempt as the solution really. 

The minimalist solution here is roughly what I went for in my attempt.

And yes it works, basically renames "first" to "key" and "second" to "value".

All things considered, I would probably recommend developers to just start loops with const Key& key = iter.first; though.

Comment: Would not `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` be more appropriate? `decltype(x)(x)` ends up doing an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin if `x` is of type `auto&&`, then `decltype(x)(x)` does no copy: `x` is guaranteed to be (some) reference type, and casting to a different reference type does no copy.  If `x` is of type `auto`, it does, and `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` is appropriate.  Typically, I perfect forward with `auto&&` variables, not `auto` variables.  The brevity of `decltype(x)(x)` is why I prefer it over `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)`, especially in lambdas.  The forward variation will work with `auto&&`, as `forward` works if you pass it a `int&&` or similar type as well as `int`.

Comment: Is there a reason to forward `x` with `decltype(x)(x)`, when we just want to access its fields?

Comment: @mik yes, there is.  If you want to learn about perfect forwarding and its issues and tricks, ask a SO question; there is too much information in this comment thread already.

Comment: Ok, I will be more specific. Is there a reason for forwarding here in case we use it with `std::map`?

Answer (score 6):

You could write a class template:

```
template <class K, class T>
struct MapElem {
    K const& key;
    T& value;

    MapElem(std::pair<K const, T>& pair)
        : key(pair.first)
        , value(pair.second)
    { }
};
```

with the advantage of being able to write `key` and `value` but with the disadvantage of having to specify the types:

```
for ( MapElem<int, std::string> kv : my_map ){
    std::cout << kv.key << " --> " << kv.value;
}
```

And that won't work if `my_map` were `const` either. You'd have to do something like:

```
template <class K, class T>
struct MapElem {
    K const& key;
    T& value;

    MapElem(std::pair<K const, T>& pair)
        : key(pair.first)
        , value(pair.second)
    { }

    MapElem(const std::pair<K const, std::remove_const_t<T>>& pair)
        : key(pair.first)
        , value(pair.second)
    { }
};

for ( MapElem<int, const std::string> kv : my_map ){
    std::cout << kv.key << " --> " << kv.value;
}
```

It's a mess. Best thing for now is to just get used to writing `.first` and `.second` and hope that the structured bindings proposal passes, which would allow for what you really want:

```
for (auto&& [key, value] : my_map) {
    std::cout << key << " --> " << value;
}
```

Comment: I know it sounds lazy, but I don't really want to type out the template parameters (they might be long!).
I feel like if constructors could deduce the type of a class, this would be the solution. But I don't think that's possible here (in some cases you can wrap it in a 'deducing factory function' I guess).

Comment: It's easy to write an alias template that will give you the type `MapElem<T, U>` from `std::map<T, U>`

Comment: You could write a range adapter that turns ranges of pairs into ranges of your key/value type.  Then you'd get `for (auto kv : as_kv(my_map))`

Comment: @Yakk I like the range adapter idea. Good team effort!

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax in the last code segment be `for (auto&& {key, value} : my_map)` (i.e. braces instead of square brackets)? Implied from section 3.4 of the [structured bindings proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf).

Comment: @Leo The latest revision switched to square brackets.

Comment: @Yakk I'm amused that of all the answers I've written, this one (which is clearly not as good as your answer) got onto [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/04/quick-qis-it-possible-in-cpp-to-iterate-over-a-stdmap-with-unpacked-key-and)...

Answer (score 6):

With modern c++17 this is now possible with [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, string> my_map;

    my_map[0] = "hello";
    my_map[1] = "world";

    for (auto&& [key, value] : my_map) {
        cout << key << "," << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Build it:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o program
```

Output:

```
$ ./program
0,hello
1,world
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing it to use `std::tie`:

```
std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
int key;
std::string value;
for(auto&& p: my_map)
{
    std::tie(key, value) = p;
    std::cout << key << ": " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Of course expressions can't be put in the for range loop, so instead a macro could be used to allow the expression:

```
#define FOREACH(var, cont) \
    for(auto && _p:cont) \
        if(bool _done = false) {} \
        else for(var = std::forward<decltype(_p)>(_p); !_done; _done = true)
```

So then `std::tie` can be used directly in the loop:

```
std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
int key;
std::string value;
FOREACH(std::tie(key, value), my_map)
{
    std::cout << key << ": " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem with `tie` is that you're copying everything, which is bad not just for the overhead but also because you can't then modify the values (if that were some desired functionality).

Comment: @Barry you sure about that? The documentation says tie returns a tuple of non const l-value references, so why is it copying everything in this example?

Comment: @Nicholas Yes. It creates a tuple of references, but the assignment is still a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of providing yet another way to *almost* do what you want, I wrote this some time ago to avoid having `.first` and `.second` all over my code:

```
auto pair2params = [](auto&& f)
{
    return [f](auto&& p) {
        f(p.first, p.second);
    };
};
```

Now you can write something like (assuming a range-based `for_each`):

```
int main()
{
    auto values = map<int, string>{
        {0, "hello"},
        {1, "world!"}
    };

    for_each(values, pair2params([](int key, const string& value) {
        cout << key << ": " << value << "\n";
    });
}
```

Running example: http://ideone.com/Bs9Ctm

Comment: Note: as implemented, it requires a C++14 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I typically prefer a KISS approach for this:

```
template<typename KeyValuePair>
typename KeyValuePair::first_type& key(KeyValuePair& kvp)
{
    return kvp.first;
}

template<typename KeyValuePair>
const typename KeyValuePair::first_type& key(const KeyValuePair& kvp)
{
    return kvp.first;
}

template<typename KeyValuePair>
void key(const KeyValuePair&& kvp) = delete;

template<typename KeyValuePair>
typename KeyValuePair::second_type& value(KeyValuePair& kvp)
{
    return kvp.second;
}

template<typename KeyValuePair>
const typename KeyValuePair::second_type& value(const KeyValuePair& kvp)
{
    return kvp.second;
}

template<typename KeyValuePair>
void value(const KeyValuePair&& kvp) = delete;
```

with usage example like this:

```
for(auto& kvp : my_map) {
    std::cout << key(kvp) << " " << value(kvp) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Apache Mesos](https://github.com/apache/mesos), we use a macro called `foreachpair` that can be used like this:

```
foreachpair (const Key& key, const Value& value, elems) {
  /* ... */
}
```

You can of course replace `Key` and `Value` with `auto`, along with whatever qualifiers you'd like to use there. It also supports `break` and `continue`.

My latest implementation looks like this:

```
#define FOREACH_PREFIX   BOOST_PP_CAT(foreach_, __LINE__)

#define FOREACH_BODY     BOOST_PP_CAT(FOREACH_PREFIX, _body__)
#define FOREACH_BREAK    BOOST_PP_CAT(FOREACH_PREFIX, _break__)
#define FOREACH_CONTINUE BOOST_PP_CAT(FOREACH_PREFIX, _continue__)
#define FOREACH_ELEM     BOOST_PP_CAT(FOREACH_PREFIX, _elem__)
#define FOREACH_ONCE     BOOST_PP_CAT(FOREACH_PREFIX, _once__)
```

The macros above provide unique names to various components  that are used in the `foreachpair` macro by including the `__LINE__` number.

```
 1 #define foreachpair(KEY, VALUE, ELEMS)                                     \
 2   for (auto&& FOREACH_ELEM : ELEMS)                                        \
 3     if (false) FOREACH_BREAK: break; /* set up the break path */           \
 4     else if (bool FOREACH_CONTINUE = false) {} /* var decl */              \
 5     else if (true) goto FOREACH_BODY; /* skip the loop exit checks */      \
 6     else for (;;) /* determine whether we should break or continue. */     \
 7       if (!FOREACH_CONTINUE) goto FOREACH_BREAK; /* break */               \
 8       else if (true) break; /* continue */                                 \
 9       else                                                                 \
10         FOREACH_BODY:                                                      \
11         if (bool FOREACH_ONCE = false) {} /* var decl */                   \
12         else for (KEY = std::get<0>(                                       \
13                       std::forward<decltype(FOREACH_ELEM)>(FOREACH_ELEM)); \
14                   !FOREACH_ONCE; FOREACH_ONCE = true)                      \
15           for (VALUE = std::get<1>(                                        \
16                    std::forward<decltype(FOREACH_ELEM)>(FOREACH_ELEM));    \
17                !FOREACH_CONTINUE; FOREACH_CONTINUE = true)
```

I'll walk through this line by line.

1. (Start of the mess).
2. Range-based for-loop iterating over `ELEMS`.
3. We set up the **label** `FOREACH_BREAK`. We jump to this label to `break` out of this loop.
4. We set up the **control flow flag** `FOREACH_CONTINUE`. This is `true` if the current iteration exited normally, or via `continue`, and `false` if the current iteration exited via `break`.
5. We always jump to the `FOREACH_BODY` label, below.
6. This is where we intercept the control flow and inspect the `FOREACH_CONTINUE` flag to determine how we exited the current iteration.
7. If `FOREACH_CONTINUE` is `false`, we know that we exited via `break` so we jump to `FOREACH_BREAK`.
8. Otherwise, `FOREACH_CONTINUE` is `true`, and we `break` out of the `for (;;)` loop which takes us to the next iteration.
9. (Half way through the mess).
10. We always jump here from (5).
11. Set up `FOREACH_ONCE` which is just used to execute the `for` loop that declares `KEY` exactly once.
12. Declare `KEY`.
13. Forward the element properly.
14. Use `FOREACH_ONCE` to ensure that this loop is executed exactly once.
15. Declare `VALUE`.
16. Forward the element properly.
17. Use `FOREACH_CONTINUE` to ensure that this loop is executed exactly once, and to indicate whether the loop was exited via `break` or not.

**NOTE**: The use of `std::get` allows support of `std::tuple` or `std::array` coming out of the sequence as well. e.g., `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>>`

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/BHcAz8)